# Use Selenium to click a 'Load More' button until it doesn't exist (Youtube)

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to write a python script that goes to a youtube channel. Clicks on the Video Tab. Then Scrapes the webpage for content. I am all fine for scraping the content, until... I get to the load more button. The python script I have manages to click the load more button once but it never presses it again :'( How can I modify the code I have to make it click it again and again until it doesn't exist. That way, I can open up the user's complete channel and get information from every video they have. Thankyou.

```
from selenium import webdriver      
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

^^ Those are the modules that I have imported. I don't know how to add in the NoSuchElementException into my code either. Here is the code:

```
chrome_path = r"/Users/jack/Desktop/Other/Downloads/Software_and_Programs/chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
YOUTUBER_HOME_PAGE_URL = "https://www.youtube.com/user/Google/videos"
PATIENCE_TIME = 60
LOAD_MORE_BUTTON_XPATH = '//*[@id="browse-itemsprimary"]/li[2]/button/span/span[2]' 

def waitForLoad(inputXPath):
    Wait = WebDriverWait(browser, PATIENCE_TIME)
    Wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, inputXPath)))

loadMoreButtonExists = True
while loadMoreButtonExists:
    try:
        waitForLoad(LOAD_MORE_BUTTON_XPATH)
        WebDriverWait(browser, PATIENCE_TIME)
        loadMoreButton = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Load More')
        #loadMoreButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath(LOAD_MORE_BUTTON_XPATH)
        loadMoreButton.click()
    except:
        print 'we have completely loaded every video from this Youtuber. Now we will scrape the video content\n'
        loadMoreButtonExists = False
```

I have used the xpath way and that still seems not to work. I have that commented out in the code above. It would be so awesome if I could get help on this. I haven't been able to find any good answers. I believe it can be done with selenium, but if not what should I use?

Answer (score 11):

you can use following code for scrolling

```
from selenium import webdriver      
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


#browser = webdriver.Firefox()#Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
YOUTUBER_HOME_PAGE_URL = "https://www.youtube.com/user/Google/videos"
PATIENCE_TIME = 60
LOAD_MORE_BUTTON_XPATH = '//*[@id="browse-itemsprimary"]/li[2]/button/span/span[2]' 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(YOUTUBER_HOME_PAGE_URL)

while True:
    try:
        loadMoreButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@aria-label,'Load more')]")
        time.sleep(2)
        loadMoreButton.click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        break
print "Complete"
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```