# Load more option while Infinite scrolling Python web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to scroll through the webpage [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68301420/unable-to-grab-a-field-in-web-scraping-python/) and scrape their company names and their description. I'm unable to crack the 'load more' option that comes once the scrolling reaches a standstill point on the web page. How can i pierce thru the 'load more' and keep storing the content in a list or a df which i could parse later?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.cloudstack.org/")
time.sleep(2)
scroll_pause_time = 1
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")
i = 1

while True:
    
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))  
    i += 1
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  
  
    if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
        break

html_source = driver.page_source
data = html_source.encode('utf-8')
```

I tried this to click thru load more with this but i stubbed upon "ElementNotInteractableException" after that.

```
  load_more = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("next-selector")
    if load_more:
        load_more[0].click()
```

[Docs that helped me but never didn't fix the probelm overall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112138/use-selenium-to-click-a-load-more-button-until-it-doesnt-exist-youtube)

Comment: I already answered you to this question, but you removed the question with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to scrape through

```
https://www.cloudtango.org/list/?page=1
```

there is a `page` argument which can be changed as needed.

There are other arguments also like:

> country=&service=&partner=&locality=&postal_town=&administrative_area_level_1=&administrative_area_level_2=&administrative_area_level_3=&autocomplete=&companyname=&head_office=&coordenades_lat=&coordenades_lng=&orderby=&order=

Run the `loop` upto needed page , scrape page and save it as you want. There aren't more then 200 pages but

**Here's demo code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
i=0
while True:
    driver.get(f"https://www.cloudtango.org/list/?page={i}")
    i+=1
    if driver.title!="Where IT seekers find Cloud Service Providers - Cloudtango":
        break
```

We are using infinity while loop, but we are checking title every time. When we reach end then that infinity loop will break.

Comment: Since i'm unsure till how many pages are there. Should i go for a while loop or give an arbitary number in the for loop and run?

Comment: @maconline then try to do like edited answer!

Comment: i don't know till how many pages are there in the website. I would like to go till the last page.

Comment: @maconline please check it works or not. If it worked then, don't forget to mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: surely will. The code stops in between while parsing the content. 
for i in range(100): 
driver.get(url) 
html=driver.page_source 
data=html.encode('utf-8')
soup= bs4.BeautifulSoup(data,'html-parser')
fin= soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'company'}
for x in fin:
res= each.find('img')['alt']
dat.append(x)

Comment: You are asking as should I do this? or telling me it stopped in `100th` itteration?

Comment: Your code is iterating through the page, it works well but it doesn't parse the contents till that page.

Comment: what does _"till that page"_ mean?

Comment: I'm trying to go till the last page and collect the company name and it's description and write it in a csv file. The problem with your code is that the website blocks me after 45-50 iterations and warns me with a security message.

Comment: What's not my code problem but, that is websites blocking you to scrape! Changing `User-Agent` could solve that problem probably!

Comment: They use CAPTCHA to prevent automated processes.